# Mascaras, coordenadas y loop en Python

Tags: python

Estoy empezando con Python y quería saber si alguien podría ayudarme, necesito a través de una mascara recortar un fragmento de una imagen, y luego los valores de las coordenadas almacenarlos y utilizarlos para otro loop que recorra las demás imágenes dentro de la carpeta a la que corresponden.

Lo que llevo es lo siguiente:

```
# import the necessary packages
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy as np

# initialize the list of reference points and boolean indicating
# whether cropping is being performed or not
refPt = []
cropping = False

def click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):
    # grab references to the global variables
    global refPt, cropping

    # if the left mouse button was clicked, record the starting
    # (x, y) coordinates and indicate that cropping is being
    # performed
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        refPt = [(x, y)]
        cropping = True

    # check to see if the left mouse button was released
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        # record the ending (x, y) coordinates and indicate that
        # the cropping operation is finished
        refPt.append((x, y))
        cropping = False

        # draw a rectangle around the region of interest
        cv2.rectangle(image, refPt[0], refPt[1], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("image", image)

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", default="./clarin/00000004.jpg",help="Path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image, clone it, and setup the mouse callback function
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
clone = image.copy()
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", click_and_crop)

# keep looping until the 'q' key is pressed
while True:
    # display the image and wait for a keypress
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the 'r' key is pressed, reset the cropping region
    if key == ord("r"):
        image = clone.copy()

    # if the 'c' key is pressed, break from the loop
    elif key == ord("c"):
        break

# if there are two reference points, then crop the region of interest
# from teh image and display it
if len(refPt) == 2:
    roi = clone[refPt[0][1]:refPt[1][1], refPt[0][0]:refPt[1][0]]
    cv2.imshow("ROI", roi)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


# close all open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hasta ahí busco la primera imagen que usaré como modelo, y puedo recortar el fragmento que necesito y lo muestro en otro frame, ahora bien, quiero usar las coordenadas que me trae este corte y que ejecute este mismo procedimiento de forma automática en el resto de las imágenes de mi carpeta. en este caso estoy usando periódicos y recortando el título, que tienden a ubicarse en el mismo lugar por lo general, para ver como ocurre el entrenamiento.

Si alguien puede ayudarme les agradecería mucho, besos!

Comment: Hola Natalia, me surgen unas cuantas dudas ¿La ruta del directorio sería la misma que la del argumento --image, el directorio de trabajo actual de la terminal o se lo pasarías como argumento?¿Se puede asumir que ese directorio solo contiene imágenes? Por otro lado, dado que haces un recorte en base a coordenadas absolutas ¿se asume que todas las imágenes tienen el mismo tamaño? Si esto último no se cumple, el recorte del resto de las imágenes puede perder sentido y tendrías que decidir como proceder, por ejemplo relativizando las coordenadas en base al tamaño de la imagen.

Comment: Hola, cómo estás? respondo las dudas en el mismo orden:
1- Sí, la ruta del directorio es la misma que está en el argumento image
2- Sí, el directorio solo va a contener imágenes y además con la misma extensión.
3- S{i, todas las imágenes tendrán el mismo tamaño